# dictionary inside column of a dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, numpy

I have a pandas dataframe that has a column like this :

```
9834    {'id': 5426, 'name': 'Solana', 'symbol': 'SOL'...
9835    {'id': 1839, 'name': 'BNB Smart Chain (BEP20)'...
9836    {'id': 1027, 'name': 'Ethereum', 'symbol': 'ET...
9837    {'id': 1839, 'name': 'BNB Smart Chain (BEP20)'...
9838    {'id': 1027, 'name': 'Ethereum', 'symbol': 'ET...
9839    {'id': 1027, 'name': 'Ethereum', 'symbol': 'ET...
9840    {'id': 1027, 'name': 'Ethereum', 'symbol': 'ET...
9841    {'id': 1839, 'name': 'BNB Smart Chain (BEP20)'...
9842    {'id': 1027, 'name': 'Ethereum', 'symbol': 'ET...
9843    {'id': 1839, 'name': 'BNB Smart Chain (BEP20)'...
```

I want to make a condition on the whole dataframe based on the id value.

I did many attempts but failed.

```
only_solana = df[df['platform']['id']==5426]
```

it says key error, it cannot access 'id' which is inside the column 'platform'.

Any help is welcome, and thank you in advance.

Comment: use `str` to slice: `df['platform'].str['id']==5426`

Comment: thank you, I didn't know about str slicing

Comment: I don't know why the question is closed, the other post doesn't talk about str slicing and is different, it doesn't quite answer and solve the issue like you did guys.

Comment: the question was the same, it hadn't been updated for a while I added the `str` method to it ;)

Comment: so you cannot ask on stack overflow similar questions if there is no perfect answer for the question ?

Comment: because for my case str perfectly solves the issue, and there was no answer having it before I asked

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`Series.str.get`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.get.html) and compare in [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
only_solana = df[df['platform'].str.get('id')==5426]
```